# How to check if dictionary contains a bool values in Swift iOS?

Tags: swift

Like in objective c I write:

```
if([[dictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"] boolValue])
{
    // action after condition is true
}
```

How do we write this in Swift? I have'nt been able to figure this out.

Comment: There are to many sites providing conversion of objective c to swift, you can search that

Comment: Did you use `NSDictionary` in Swift? Or `[String: Bool]` like you should? Also note that a dictionary with boolean values is basically a set.

Comment: That is coming in response from server. The answer given by Nirav worked for me. But apparently he has deleted his answer.
What worked for me was 
"if let booleanValue = dict["MyKey"] as? Bool, booleanValue"
which checked for the value is true or not as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if let booleanValue = dict["MyKey"] as? Bool {

}
```

This utilises optional binding in Swift, and will only enter the if statement in the case that booleanValue can be derived from "MyKey". It also has the added benefit that `booleanValue` has actually been declared as a constant within the scope of the if statement.